# step by step usage of ancestry gem in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i am an newbie to ROR, now i need to develop a webpage with tree control and have following operations such as adding an node, editing an node and deleteing an node using jquery ajax. There is no limit on the number of levels.

Could anyone guide me how to start with or point me an tutorial ( step by step) to proceed further?

Regards,
Sudhir C.N.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry)?

Comment: Yes, but my requirement is the tree should be collapsible and upon selecting an node, i should be able to do add, edit, delete and display the tree. Is there any example?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned previously, you might need to have a look at [railscast](http://www.railscasts.com) first to under Rails and then you can use a gem called [acts_as_tree](https://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree) which would do all the job for you.

Good luck but you will see it's very powerful.